# BufferedReader not reading past empty line

Tags: java, http, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to figure out why my BufferedReader (reading from an InputStream) just hangs and doesn't read after an empty line is received.

Trying to read in a POST request that looks something like:

```
POST /test.php HTTP/1.0
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: text/html;

postData=whatever&moreData...
```

I know the post data is being sent correctly (in the above format), however I'm unable to retrieve the posted data. I would expect the following code to print out the post data then hang waiting for more.. but, what actually happens is it hangs after the "Content-Type" line.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
}
```

Code used to obtain stream:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code used to obtain the stream

Comment: I expected bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new URL( "http://..." ).openConnection()); Why using a socket for HTTP?

Comment: this is part of a simple server - so sockets are needed

Comment: server - I'm reading the POST request sent - hence trying to read the posted data (after empty line) but can't retrieve it

Comment: If this is part of *server*, why is the socket handle called `clientSocket`? Does that mean "the socket with which to talk with a client?"

Comment: Please include the code you are using to send the data from the client.

Comment: Does it print the blank line? Does the client close its end of the socket? If not, your `InputStream` won't report EOF, and if the POST message body is not terminated by a CR or LF, `BufferedReader` won't return the content for the partial line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `POST` method will not add a newline character at the end. What you need to do is get the `Content-Length` and after the last empty line read that many characters.

*Example*

Let's assume we have a following `HTML` page:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:12345/test.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="postData" value="whatever"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="postData2" value="whatever"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now we start a very simple server which somehow resembles your code (this code is full of wholes, but that's not the issue):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        final Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int contentLength = -1;
        while (true) {
            final String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            final String contentLengthStr = "Content-Length: ";
            if (line.startsWith(contentLengthStr)) {
                contentLength = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(contentLengthStr.length()));
            }

            if (line.length() == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // We should actually use InputStream here, but let's assume bytes map
        // to characters
        final char[] content = new char[contentLength];
        bufferedReader.read(content);
        System.out.println(new String(content));
    }
}
```

When we load the page in our favorite browser and press the `Go` button, we should some the content of the `POST` body in the console.

Comment: I know that this is just sample code, but, but, but... The space after the "Content-Length" header field's colon is not required, per RFC 2616 §4.2. Also, just for the benefit of future readers looking to lift code against our advice, the "Content-Length" header is not required to indicate the boundary of message body. RFC 2616 §4.4 defines the four options: a "Content-Length" header, chunked transfer-coding, the "multipart/byteranges" media type, or the client's termination of the connection indicating EOF to the server. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: @seh Well, basically I didn't want to include the code for a fully-fledged HTTP server. The example was supposed to illustrate why the code of OP does not work and a possible solution in a very limited case.

Comment: I understand; hence my mention of "sample code." @Aubin had asked why the OP wasn't using `HttpURLConnection` here, and the reply was, "[T]his is part of a simple server - so sockets are needed." That's enough to have me worried about what he is building.

Comment: that was the problem - I wasn't using the InputStream by reading into char/byte array. Thanks!

Comment: @seh what I gave is only a small part of all the code - I knew the other bits worked as I've run tests on them, it was just extracting this posted data that was the problem. But all sorted now :)

Comment: wouldn't this code blow up as soon as bufferedReader.readLine() is null..?

Comment: "if (line.length() == 0)" This isn't what you want at all. A zero-length line is totally possible, it doesn't mean there's no more content...